# Using fprintf to output variables side by side

Tags: matlab, matrix, printf

I'm having trouble using fprintf. I'm trying to print variables side by side. For example, the way it has to look like is A1 then another value. Then new line, A2 and another value. New line, A3 and another value from variable 'A' and so on.

```
f2 = 1:124;
fprintf(fileID,'A%f \t %f \n',f2',A);
```

This code prints:

```
A1 2
A3 4
A5 6
```

and so on. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through them all:

```
for i = 1:124
  fprintf(fileID,'A%f \t %f \n',f2(i),A(i))
end
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!